# iPad Synching with Exchange 2007 is Losing Contacts

Tags: exchange-2007, contacts, ipad

We have a user who has an iPad that is synching to our Exchange 2007 SP1 Server.  She is reporting that her contacts are being "eaten", which we take to mean are being slowly deleted over time.  This user also has a BlackBerry that is synching through a Blackberry Enterprise Server.

I have two questions -

1) Has anyone run into this situation of "self-deleting" contacts or does anyone have any idea what is going on?

2) Can anyone give insight into usage of iPads in their Active Directory/Exchange environment?

Update:

I was just told that the contacts are not missing, but the information inside the contacts is missing.  Also that there is another user having the same issue who is using an Android OS phone that synchs to our Exchange server.

Comment: I don't know why someone (DanBig) would post here to say it doesnt affect them, when they aren't testing with an iPad (only a iPod Touch).

But i can attest to the fact that this indeed is affecting one of my users as well.

They have a BB Bold 9700, and a 1st Generation iPad 3G with 4.2 iOS.
And at seemingly random times the contacts have been updated, in some instances stripping out the email address of someone who happens to be in the GAL (Global address list in Exchange) and also in his personal contacts.

As the ipad and BB both sync his personal contacts as well as exchange, 
and

Comment: @craig if you have a distinct question of your own, please use the **Ask Question** button in the top right corner of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an iPad user here, but have a couple iPhones and iPod touches connecting to Exch2007 via EAS. I also have used BES as well in conjunction with a user that had an iPod touch, with no issue.

1. No, never had issue with iOS deleting contacts, calendar appointments or mail.
2. Assuming you are connecting via EAS, then the connection is really no different than say, Outlook connecting to Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it's the Blackberry, especially if you're utilizing encryption on it.

Check for any contacts that have had every data field replaced by `<Content Protection is Enabled>` (this is the transitive message that gets displayed when decryption isn't done, but sometimes get written back to exchange as the actual contact or calendar data), and if you haven't already, check if there's anything interesting going on in the Sync Issues folder of the user's mailbox.

If the contacts are being overwritten by the content protection, the cure tends to be a wipe and reactivate.

Comment: I second the nomination of blackberry as the culprit